# Sklearn OneVsRestClassifier prediction probabilities do not amount to 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, xgboost, multiclass-classification

So I am working on a multiclass problem with 6 outcome classes. I am using a OneVsRest classifier and trying to retrieve the prediction probabilties for every class using .predict_proba.

I was expecting the sum of the prediction probabilities of all classes for every observation to come out as one, however that is not the case.

```
predictor =  OneVsRestClassifier(xgb.XGBClassifier)
predictor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = predictor.predict_proba(X_test)
print(y_pred[1])
```

My output is: [0.11484083 0.02525082 0.02969465 0.58868223 0.09889702 0.03193117]

Can that be correct?

Comment: What is `y_pred_outer_loop`?

Comment: Most likely, you have a multilabel case, try `predictor.multilabel_` to see if it's true. Note that in multilabel case the probabilities don't necessary sum up to 1.

Answer (score 2):

From the document of OneVsRestClassifier, `this strategy consists in fitting one classifier per class. For each classifier, the class is fitted against all the other classes.`. For example, if you want to classify dog, cat, and bird with OneVsRestClassifier, it will train 3 models.

- first model will be trained to check if your data is dog or not.
- second model will be trained to check if your data is bird or not.
- third model will be trained to check if your data is cat or not.

Three models will be trained independently as a binary-class classification. So, the probability from three models do not sum up to 1.